# Creating Toplevel after receiveing some input on socket

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I'm using this forum for some time, but first time asking question.
I have problem with one tkinter application. It's simple chat server - client program, where chat is something like Skype. I have a friend list, and when I select friend from list, click chat, new window (toplevel) opens. Then I can send messages to friend.
Problem is on the other side. It's working fine if chat window is opened on the other side, but if it's not, I'm trying to create in by calling function that creates new toplevel. And here program freezes (on the side of friend).

```
def bChatPress(self, event=None):
        def closeChatClient():
            chatClient.destroy()
            del self.chatClients[friend]

        if self.friend=='':
            index = self.lbFriends.curselection()
            if index:
                friend = self.lbFriends.get(index)
                if friend not in self.chatClients:
                    chatClient=ChatClient(self, self.user, friend)
                    chatClient.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeChatClient)
                    self.chatClients[friend] = chatClient
        else:
            chatClient=ChatClient(self, self.user, self.friend)
            chatClient.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeChatClient)
            self.chatClients[self.friend] = chatClient
            self.friend=''

def receiveMessage(self):
        def loop():
            print('threadstart')
            while self.loged:
                try:
                    message = self.socket.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
                    print(message)
                    if '{LOGIN}' in message:
                        threading.Thread(target=self.login).start()
                    elif '{LOGOUT}' in message:
                        pass
                    elif '{CONNECT}' in message:
                        self.connect(message.replace('{CONNECT}',''))
                    elif '{DISCONNECT}' in message:
                        self.disconnect()
                    elif '{ADD FRIEND}' in message:
                        self.populateFriendsList(message.replace('{ADD FRIEND}',''))
                    elif '{DELETE FRIEND}' in message:
                        self.populateFriendsList(message.replace('{DELETE FRIEND}',''))
                    elif '{USER CONNECT}' in message:
                        self.checkOnline()
                    elif '{USER DISCONNECT}' in message:
                        self.checkOnline()
                    elif '{CHECK ONLINE}' in message:
                        self.populateFriendsList(message.replace('{CHECK ONLINE}',''))
                    elif '{MESSAGE}' in message:
                        self.processMessage(message.replace('{MESSAGE}',''))
                except Exception as error:
                    pass

        threading.Thread(target=loop).start()
```

This is function for creating chat window. It's working fine when I create window by clicking the button, but it's not working when I call this function from receiveMessage function (this is loop for listening socket)

Did anybody had this problem before?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the receive message code please,and the error too

Comment: There is no usual error, program just freezes, without any notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call tkinter functions or widget methods from any thread except the one that created the root window.

Comment: But the function for creating toplevel is inside of class of main window.

Comment: @user3169214: It doesn't matter where it's defined -- which thread is it being called from?

Comment: It's called from thread for receiving messages. Do You want to say that if I just run loop by calling function, rather than calling it through threading, I'll be able to create toplevel?

Comment: @user3169214: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying you can't create widgets from more than one thread.

Comment: I'm not getting this... Main thread is mainloop. Only other thread is in messageReceive.

Comment: @user3169214: Do you mean "receiveMessage" rather than "messageReceive"? If so, and if populateFriendsList is what creates a new Toplevel, that's the problem because it's calling it from a different thread. Note: I'm only assuming that populateFriendsList is what is creating the toplevel since your question doesn't show that.

Comment: Yes, sorry. New toplevel is creted in bChatPress. ChatClient is class which ihnerits toplevel. self.friend is variable which is None if bChatPress is called by pressing button, and have some value if it's called from processMessage (which is called from receiveMessage).

Comment: Any other idea how to make a window appears after receiving some predefined message on socket?

Comment: @user3169214: you need to post a message on a thread-safe queue, and poll the queue from your GUI thread. There are examples on this site, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/16700254/7432